# SOQL query filter WHERE by month

Tags: soql, date

I have a custom object having a Date field Expense__Date__c

I need to perform a soql query on the custom object where Expense__Date__c = [THIS_MONTH](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

So my query looks like

```
List<CustomObj__c> list = [select Name from CustomObj__c where Expense__Date__c = THIS_MONTH];
```

But it gives an error Unexpected token : THIS_MONTH

When I try to do something like this

```
List<CustomObj__c> list = [select Name from CustomObj__c where Expense__Date__c.month() = :Date.Today().Month()];
```

It gives in error unexpected token ')'

How do I perform this filter - where the month for that date field is current month, in a soql query?

Thanks

Comment: Odd. Your query looks correct. For example this query works just fine: [Select ID From Opportunity where CloseDate = THIS_MONTH]. Are you trying to build this query dynamically? If so then THIS_MONTH will not work.

Comment: No I am not building it dynamically. It is as it is given above. I too find no fault in it but dont know why it wont work

Answer (score 5):

Confirming @Eric, your query

```
List<CustomObj__c> list = [SELECT Name 
                           FROM CustomObj__c 
                           WHERE Expense__Date__c = THIS_MONTH];
```

is validated by the following:

- [Date Format and Date Literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)
- [SOQL Date Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm)

I tried out a version of your query myself, and it worked fine.

---

Though this is besides the point (the Date Literals work), there is always the option of "rolling your own" by something like the following:

```
Date startOfMonth = Date.today().toStartOfMonth();
Date startOfNextMonth = startOfMonth.addMonths(1);
List<CustomObj__c> list = [SELECT Name 
                           FROM CustomObj__c 
                           WHERE Expense__Date__c >= :startOfMonth
                           AND Expense_Date__c < :startOfNextMonth];
```

Comment: So I just found out that I am only facing this issue when I am working in Eclipse. I saved the class through Salesforce apex class editor and it saved but when I work on it through Eclipse it fails to save. Any reason why this happens?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the Plugin.   https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000094FZIY